# Как отредактировать контект кнопки при её нажатии?

Tags: c#, discord

```
public async Task MyButtonHandler(SocketMessageComponent component)
{
    switch (component.Data.CustomId)
    {
        case "0":
            await component.RespondAsync($"{component.User.Mention} проголосовал(а) за {Convert.ToInt32(component.Data.CustomId) + 1}й вариант");
            await component.Message.ModifyAsync(msg => msg.Content = "text");
            break;
    }
}
```

Я хочу отредактировать текст кнопки при её нажатии. Объект класса `SocketMessageComponent` содержит информацию о ней. Но я не знаю, как обратиться именно к тексту кнопки, а не к тексту сообщения.

Comment: Пересоздайте кнопку целиком (`msg.Components = new ComponentBuilder()....`), либо пробуйте искать в этом `Components` нужный объект (тут не уверен).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, текст кнопки доступен только для чтения. Единственный выход копировать данные старой кнопки и изменять их для новой